# Pandas runtime error /anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13 missing_dependencies

Tags: pandas

I need to do some stuff using pandas.
Inside my python file, I wrote this:

```
sys.path.append("/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
import pandas as pd
```

When I run the program,I get this:

```
 File "/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13
    missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I installed Anaconda, and I can verify that pandas is available.
My working environment is inside Anaconda's virtual environment, where python version is 3.8.
When I "conda deactivate", my python version is 2.7.

When I login to the server, my Anaconda env is already activated, and I get a prompt like this:

```
(base) user0@optiplex:~$
```

"conda list" tells me my pandas version is 1.0.5, and numpy is 1.18.5.

I have already updated Anaconda using "conda update --all". No improvement.

Some diagnostics:

```
(base) user0@optiplex:~$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/user0/anaconda3/bin/python'


>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip', '/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python3.8', 
'/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', 
'/home/user0/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

Someone please give me some hints.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I tried different keywords and googled, and landed on exactly this item in stack overflow!
It mentions may be there is python version mismatch.

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/import-pandas-%E3%81%A7-pandas-init-py-%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-syntaxerror-%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

I was running my code inside another program that uses python 2.x internally, so it could be the case, I don't know.  I don't know much about python, specially working env setup, so I cannot make anymore comments.

Second, I ran the code once again, right after the first error, and the second time, the program worked.  I don't know what to make of it either.

BTW, AtanuCSE, thank you for formatting my question!